# Parametrize Ant script to build two versions of same file

Tags: ant

We have a Java applet project and we generate the wrapper HTML using Ant, it looks a bit like this:

```
<target name="build-applet" description="Build web applet" depends="set-build-properties, set-properties">  
    <antcall target="clean" />
    <antcall target="clean-applet" />
    <antcall target="set-version" />
    <antcall target="compile" />
    <antcall target="jar" />
    <antcall target="applet" />
</target>

<target name="applet">      
    <replace file="${applet.dir}/${applet.html.file}">          
        <replacefilter token="@jar.file@" value="${applet.jar.file}"/>
        <replacefilter token="@assets.file@" value="${applet.assets.file}"/>
        <replacefilter token="@codebase@" value="${applet.codebase}"/>
</target>
```

Note that `${applet.codebase}` has to be the URL where the applet is loaded from e.g mysite.com/game. It's set in a properties file.

Now I want to be able to build this applet to two different locations, part of a live/test setup. e.g one is accessed at mysite.com/game and the other at mysite.com/test. I have it almost working, except for `${applet.codebase}` because this needs to be different in each case. I thought I could have `${applet.codebase}` and `${applet.codebase_test}` but I don't know how to do this. Maybe there's a way to pass a flag into the `applet` target from `build-applet`, and add two top-level targets `build-applet-live` and `build-applet-test` which just call `build-applet` with the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply `ant -Dapplet.codebase=whatever build.xml`, means set ${applet_codebase} as userproperty (= those properties set via -Dkey=value) ?

Comment: Because ant-scripts and associated property files are part of our Eclipse project... unless I misunderstood you your solution means passing command-line variables to ant?

Comment: Yes, also possible with Eclipse Run As > Ant Build... second entry

Comment: Another slightly related refactor:  change the antcalls to clean, clean-applet,set-version, compile and jar to entries on the depends list of build-applet.  It's much cleaner to let ant manage the dependency graph for you.  I also wholeheartedly agree that applet should go away in favor of passing the param into ant, or at least should be a macro